# The multi-part identifier "CDB.dbo.aspnet_Users.UserId" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server

I am running this query:

```
  SELECT [CDB].[dbo].[AccessLog].username
  FROM [CDB].[dbo].[AccessLog] 
  join [CDB].[dbo].[CUsers] as ctus on [CDB].[dbo].[AccessLog].username = ctus.UserName
  join [CDB].[dbo].[CUsers] as ctu on [CDB].[dbo].[aspnet_Users].UserId = ctu.UserId
  where [CDB].[dbo].[aspnet_Users].LastActivityDate >= Convert(datetime, '2017-01-01' )
```

but I receive these errors:

> The multi-part identifier "CDB.dbo.aspnet_Users.UserId"
> could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part
> identifier "CDB.dbo.aspnet_Users.LastActivityDate" could
> not be bound.

Comment: That's because you haven't joined the table `CDB.dbo.aspnet_Users`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join syntax is off, try this:

```
select al.username
from [cdb].[dbo].[AccessLog] as al
  inner join [cdb].[dbo].[CUsers] as ctus 
    on al.username = ctus.UserName
  inner join [cdb].[dbo].[aspnet_Users] as au
    on au.UserId = ctus.UserId
where au.LastActivityDate >= convert(datetime,'2017-01-01')
```